# How can I change the configuration of existing docker?

Tags: linux, docker, container

I have a docker container, which was created using docker run command and basic command line options.

Now the docker is running and I would like to add more options i.e. RAM, mount new partition and change the process user from root to non-root user.

How can I change the configuration of existing docker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Create an image from the existing container (`docker commit...`)
- Use that image as the base (`FROM ...`) in a Dockerfile that defines/replaces what you want. AFAIK RAM usage is not defined by the container.